# How to enable paredit mode on all clojure, closurescript and elisp buffers automatically?

Tags: spacemacs, paredit

I want to enable `paredit-mode` on all clojure, cljs and elisp buffers by default, which is probably going to happen through the `.spacemacs` file. This is what I have so far in the `user-config` function of my `.spacemacs`:

```
;; paredit autoload
  (autoload 'enable-paredit-mode "paredit" "Turn on pseudo-structural editing of Lisp code." t)
  (add-hook 'clojure-mode #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'clojurescript-mode #'enable-paredit-mode)
```

But it doesn't really work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should work. Can you explain why you think it does not? Does the similar setting work in elisp? Maybe there's a conflict with the `clojure*` modes. Please edit the question and add more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically enable paredit mode on all clojure, closurescript and elisp buffers automatically?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58741/how-to-automatically-enable-paredit-mode-on-all-clojure-closurescript-and-elisp)

Comment: Please don't open duplicate questions.